# CiviVolunteer Create new project error

Tags: drupal, civivolunteer

I installed the CiviCRM plugin "CiviVolunteer". When I try to add a project, there is a form. However, when I submit the form, there is no response. But when I check the Drupal log, I find that when I click “add project”, it goes to (/civicrm/vol#/volunteer/manage/0), and the following errors appear:

Warning: Undefined array key “buttons” in include() (file /var/www/project/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/zh_TW/%%ED/ED7/ED78F5CC%%formButtons.tpl.php on line 38)
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in include() (file /var/www/project/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/zh_TW/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php on line 110)
Warning: Undefined array key “phone_ext-Primary” in include() (file /var/www/project/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/zh_TW/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php on line 110)
Warning: Undefined array key “perm” in include() (file /var/www/project/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/zh_TW/%%89/896/89673E6E%%ProfileTemplates.tpl.php on line 99)